# Angular datepipe with specific timezone

Tags: angular

In my angular 5 project I have to convert some data to a specific timezone, to do this I have installed [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/) and it works well, but I have a problem when formatting data in the HTML using angular DatePipe.

Some dates have to be converted to a specific timezone, not in the browser/system timezone(Italy) is it possible with built-in pipes?

I don't want to use fixed GMT like the example:

```
<!--output '2015-06-15 05:03 PM GMT+9'-->
    <p>The custom date is {{today | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z':'+0900'}</p>
```

because for example in italy we have +1 for winter time and +2 for summertime, so it can't be hardcoded.

Comment: Why don't you format it with moment? You can set locale in moment which takes into account summertime. ps not down voter

Comment: The agular documentation specify this use for date pipe: 

date_expression | date[:format[:timezone[:locale]]]

you can define the timezone as they mention:

timezone to be used for formatting. It understands UTC/GMT and the continental US time zone abbreviations, but for general use, use a time zone offset, for example, '+0430' (4 hours, 30 minutes east of the Greenwich meridian) If not specified, the local system.

Check the official docs https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: And if the date can't be hardcoded ,you can set the locale instead adding hours. https://angular.io/api/core/LOCALE_ID